# is it possible that virtual memory can decrease L1 cache miss?

Tags: linux, caching, arm, virtual-memory

I have a A53 core, and did some test.

1. first I configure the MMU to make the virtual memory address == the physical memory address, and do some Matrix computation.
2. Second I configure the MMU to enable the address translation, and do some Matrix computation.

After collect the pmu info, I found that the first method gain more L1 cache miss that the second method. I guess that it may because the address translation makes it possible for "far away" data to be located in "neer" physical address. Which benefits the L1 cache.

I also found that when I do the test in Linux Kernel mode(no virtual address) and Linux User mode(with virtual address), the User mode can gain less L1 cache miss.

Is it right?

Comment: Your premises seems wrong. Once you enable MMU **only virtual** memory addressing is used. The fact that "virtual memory == the physical memory" does not cancel translation. "Linux Kernel mode(no virtual address)" is that really possible to run Linux Kernel w/o enabling MMU ?

Comment: virtual memory == physical memory means that I fill in the page table to make the virtual memory address == physical memory address.

Comment: "configure the MMU to **enable** the address translation", that really makes an impression that in first case translation is disabled.

Comment: Anyway, I don't see how cache is affected by memory translation (it could, to be pedantic, but really minor). Cache is updated during memory access (reading/writing) or during prefetch. Translation is done per memory page (commonly 4KB), so if you access memory on same page there is no translations whatever. If you read data from different random memory pages that would cause translation. But even that is partly leveled by TLB cache.

Answer (score 1):

ARM caches are normally VIVT, which stands for 'Virtual index, virtual tag'.  This means that the cache index is using the virtual address to calculate the set and way.  As your code runs at the same virtual address, the physical mapping will not matter to caching effects.

It is possible that the Cortex-A53 has a PIPT data cache and then it will directly make sense as you may have altered the set/way calculation depending on the cache structure.  A more common technique is to align data to get similar effects.  Certainly a PIPT cache patterns will be affected by the MMU mappings.

Often DDR will have faster modes between banks, etc.  It is possible that some code is delayed and speculative execution may cause a different memory access pattern and this in turn could cause L1 cache behavior.

So your observation is probably correct, but may not be a direct consequence of the MMU and cache, but the underlying memory technology.  This may also involve the L2 cache system which is often PIPT.

See: [Wikipedia page coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Page_coloring)

Comment: As I remember Cortex-A53 has VIVT for instruction cache and PIPT for data cache. Anyway "PIPT data cache and then it will directly make sense as you may have altered the set/way calculation", sorry I don't see how straight mapping in first case would make lookup in cache really different. Could you elaborate this point please. And TS said that PMU reports more cache misses, even if lookup is longer that still would not be cache miss, I think.

Comment: With speculative execution, the cpu may speculate on alternate instructions during the delay.

Comment: I thought we are talking about L1-Data-Cache, not L1-Instruction-Cache. Though reading question again, author did not specify which one misbehaved. Still that does not make sense how the mapping way make difference except getting luck/unluck with that particular chip.

Comment: The speculative execution can be an instruction that accesses data.  So, it can be either L1 I/D cache.  Absolutely, I am saying luck/unluck... but it is just to say, it may be observed even with a VIVT cache.